# How do you partially-match IDs in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I have a set of ACLs in Couch and I want to create a view that matches applicable ones.  So, given the data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "/protected",
    "type": "valid-user"
  },
  {
    "_id": "/protected/group1",
    "type": "require group group1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "/protected/group1/public",
    "type": "public"
  },
  {
    "_id": "/protected/group2",
    "type": "require group group2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "/admin",
    "type": "require user admin"
  }
]
```

I'd like to create a view that'd allow me to pass in a string and have it find the "best" (that is to say the longest) match.

The best I've been able to do is to create a view that returns the ID split into an array and then spam queries trimming the last element off until I get a match.  Surely there's a way to do this on the server side ...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [list function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List) to accomplish that.

Comment: I've spent a couple of days banging on list functions and haven't gotten any traction.  As near as I can tell, they exist only to transform the native JSON into something else like XML.  Perhaps you could expand on what you where thinking?

Comment: Can you give me and example string and expected match? Just want to make sure I understand what you're trying to do fully.